# How can I disable Read Only in Eclipse task bar?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse shows read only at random times to any  and I can't edit that file.  Usually happens after debugging?  How can I get rid of this Read only? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I would assume that the file you are looking at is a decompiled class file that may be part of a jar file, not a Java source file (see the different icon in the tab next to the file-name). You can try to create a new Java file for this class and copy the source code in it. The you have a writable file.

Comment: Also in the window title you can see that it is not a file, but probably a decompiled class. By the way, you are using a pretty old Eclipse version. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Comment: On the contrary, considering the offset indicator present in the status bar, it's pretty recent.

Comment: @nitind You right, it's Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) and "only" two releases behind (offset shown in status bar, but with old view menu icon).